# Opening a modal popup on session expire in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session, modalpopupextender

I want to open a modal popup on session expire in asp.net other than redirecting to login page. The user login from popup and stays on the same page where he was previously.

Answer (score 1):

I have always used the redirect from forms authentication, so this one is interesting.  You could return the session expiration minutes in either a hidden input or set a javascript variable for every requested page.  Then, on page load, kick off a timer so that if the user has sat on the page for your number of expiration minutes, then it automatically shows a modal dialog to login again.  That dialog would have to post to an unsecure page via AJAX, in order to avoid the redirect, and the session cookie would get returned on that post.  The problem is that if the user had timed out, then just hit F5, they'll get redirected to your login page, and I don't think you can do anything about that part because once you request a page from the server, and you are not authenticated, that result will get rendered by the browser in place of the page currently shown.  Other than F5, you could theoretically do it for everything else.

Comment: I'm using master page Michael. So what could be better?                        And thank you for your response.

Comment: Sure, np.  For what I suggested, it wouldn't matter if you used a master page or not.  Everything that happens on the client-side would just be javascript.  At the moment, I don't have any other suggestions to add.  I can try to do this in a sample project to see if it works, but may not have the time to invest.  This guy seems to do something similar to my suggestion though, by using a timer: http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2011/06/15/asp-net-how-to-show-a-popup-warning-before-session-timeout.aspx